# JavaScript function and return

Tags: javascript, function, return

```
var Double = function(number) {
   return number * 2;
};  

var number = Double(12);
console.log(number);
```

//on code academy this will run and return the number doubled as its supposed to. I put this in debug and it will not run?
//ultimately i am trying to write a function called double that takes in a number as the parameter, and returns that number doubled. 
//sorry if this is elementary but I am new to JavaScript and trying to teach myself

//Just in case anyone else is having this issue I figured out the issue in JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hu85B/351/

Comment: it's working properly though the semicolon after the end of function body is unnecessary http://jsfiddle.net/m6fpb710/

Comment: @EdHeal it's okay without semicolon. I've never seen people doing that.

Comment: why is it not giving me a value when I hit run?

Comment: @Jessica press F12 and then click the "Console" tab

Comment: [Jessica](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4283145/jessica) it works in the Chrome debugger, what tool are you using that refuses to print a value?

Comment: @Amit Joki jsfiddle.net/m6fpb710 is also doing the same thing? when i hit run it will not give a value? Is yours showing a value?

Comment: @The Brofessor I am using jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result page in jsfiddle renders html.

The Javascript function 'console.log()' outputs information to the browser console, not to the [Document Object Model (dom)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

You can view javascript console output in any browser console, I like to use [Chrome Web Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), or you can [build your own HTML to see the results](http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2013/01/26/console-log-with-jsfiddle/)

Rest assured, the function you wrote works, it just doesn't represent itself in the results part of jsfiddle.

**Edit:** formatting

**Edit 2:** If you just want the confidence your Javascript function is working, without other technical information, change `console.log(number)` to `alert(number)`

Comment: I checked it in Chrome as you suggested and it does work!! Thank you! Problem being I am need it to work in jsfiddle. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is an example of another JavaScript i worked in jsfiddle and it worked. http://jsfiddle.net/85Lp6mba/50/

Comment: Check out this fiddle by [Wayne Koorts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/38403/wayne-koorts). You just need to write the `console.log` function in the console underneath the console object in the javascript part of the fiddle.

Comment: The reason it worked, is that in Javascript, the alert function 'alert()' forces the browser to accept input before refocusing on the window. It is fundamentally different than what `console.log()` does. I would check out the free [Codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/javascript-road-trip-part-1) Javascript tutorial, it will help you out a ton!

Comment: You have been such a huge help! Thank you so much I really appreciate the information.

Comment: i have found that if you use document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = double;

Comment: but i can not get the <p></p> correct to return the actual number